# Storage values using os.stat(filename)

Tags: python-3.7, operands

I'm trying to create an EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES ONLY virus. I do not plan on spreading it. It's purpose is to grow a file to the point your storage is full and slow your computer down. It prints the size of the file every 0.001 seconds. With that, I also want to know how fast it is growing the file. The following code doesn't seem to let it run:

```
class Vstatus():
  def _init_(Status):
    Status.countspeed == True
    Status.active == True
    Status.growingspeed == 0

import time
import os
#Your storage is at risk of over-expansion. Please do not let this file run forever, as your storage will fill continuously.
#This is for educational purposes only.

while Vstatus.Status.countspeed == True:
    f = open('file.txt', 'a')
    f.write('W')
    fsize = os.stat('file.txt')
    Key1 = fsize
    time.sleep(1)
    Key2 = fsize
    Vstatus.Status.growingspeed = (Key2 - Key1)
    Vstatus.Status.countspeed = False

while Vstatus.Status.active == True:
     time.sleep(0.001)
     f = open('file.txt', 'a')
     f.write('W')
     fsize = os.stat('file.txt')
     print('size:' + fsize.st_size.__str__() + ' at a speed of ' + Vstatus.Status.growingspeed + 'bytes per second.')
```

## This is for Educational Purposes ONLY

The main error I keep getting when running the file is here:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'os.stat_result' and 'os.stat_result'

What does this mean? I thought os.stat returned an integer Can I get a fix on this?

Comment: `os_stat` returns a [`os.stat_result`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result) object.  You can't subtract them.  I don't see where in your code this is happening.  Can you post the full error?  It should include the line this error is happening on.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This is happening in the first "while" statement, where it says Key2 - Key1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vstatus.Status.growingspeed = (Key2 - Key1)
```

You can't subtract `os.stat` objects.  Your code also has some other problems.  Your loops will run sequentially, meaning that your first loop will try to estimate how quickly the file is being written to without writing anything to the file.

```
import time  # Imports at the top 
import os

class VStatus:
    def __init__(self):  # double underscores around __init__
        self.countspeed = True  # Assignment, not equality test
        self.active = True
        self.growingspeed = 0

status = VStatus()  # Make a VStatus instance

# You need to do the speed estimation and file appending in the same loop

with open('file.txt', 'a+') as f:  # Only open the file once
    start = time.time()  # Get the current time
    starting_size = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
    while status.active:  # Access the attribute of the VStatus instance
        size = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size  # Send file desciptor to stat
        f.write('W')  # Writing more than one character at a time will be your biggest speed up
        f.flush()  # make sure the byte is written
        if status.countspeed:
            diff = time.time() - start
            if diff >= 1:  # More than a second has gone by
                status.countspeed = False
                status.growingspeed = (os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size - starting_size)/diff  # get rate of growth
        else:
            print(f"size: {size} at a speed of {status.growingspeed}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the code rewrite, I am a novice python programmer after all. Not really that good at programming, but I can use this as an example for other code. Thank you!